# Angular ng-if to set a class in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am creating pagination buttons that call specific content through custom angular directives. These buttons are created via ng-repeat.

```
            <div class="margin-less row">
                <a ng-repeat="i in getNumber(9)" href="#/5-4-9_novena?day={{$index + 1}}">
                    <div class="small-1 panel-default columns pagination-panel" ng-if { ng-class="current: $index + 1 == date.weekday"}>
                        <h4 class="panel-title ">{{$index + 1}}</h4></div>
                </a>
            </div>
```

I attempted to use ng-if to add a class "current" on the pagination link that matches the link whose index matches {{date.weekday}}. However, to my disappointment I couldn't get it to add the class when the index matched the scope. Am I missing anything?

Comment: So what is exactly your question?

Comment: Just clarified the question better. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About ng-class you could use something like

```
<div class="small-1 panel-default columns pagination-panel" ng-class="{ current: $index + 1 == date.weekday}">
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an ng-if to achieve that. Also, the ng-if syntax is completely different.

change `ng-if { ng-class="current: $index + 1 == date.weekday"}`

to

```
data-ng-class="{current: $index + 1 === date.weekday}"
```

Answer (score 1):

For this case it's better to use ng-class:

```
ng-class="{current: $index == selected}"
```

Answer (score 0):

For Both condition `ng-if` and `ng-class`

Change This:

```
 <div class="small-1 panel-default columns pagination-panel" ng-if { ng-class="current: $index + 1 == date.weekday"}>
```

To:

```
<div class="small-1 panel-default columns pagination-panel" ng-if="$index + 1 == date.weekday" ng-class="{'current': $index + 1 == date.weekday }">
```